# Autoconf Append to Output Variable and Program Specific LIBS

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

Using autoconf in configure.ac I need to append to an output variable.

Specifically I want to append to the LIBS variable differently for each of my programs (myprogram1 and myprogram2 in the Makefile.am). Lets imagine myprogram1 requires a -lboost_python and myprogram2 requires -losg.

Essentially some programs require certain libs while others do not. Here is an example of what I am doing. Of course AC_SUBST does an assignment (= vs +=) from what I understand so that doesn't work.

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([boost_python], [main], [AC_SUBST([myprogram1_LIBS], ["-lboost_python"])                      
  AC_DEFINE([HAVE_LIBBOOST_PYTHON], [1], [Define if you have libboost_python])],                  
  [AC_MSG_FAILURE([boost_python library not found])])  
AC_CHECK_LIB([osg], [main], [AC_SUBST([myprogram2_LIBS], ["-losg"])                      
  AC_DEFINE([HAVE_LIBOSG], [1], [Define if you have libosg])],                  
  [AC_MSG_FAILURE([osg library not found])])
```

What I need is for the myprogram1_SOURCES to be built with the first lib and the myprogram2_SOURCES to be built with the second lib.

Is there an AC_APPEND_SUBST type macro I can use? And/or is there a better way for me to do what I need to do to build different programs with different libraries being linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `AC_CHECK_LIB` calls and such do the right thing (if they don't, have you tried using the macros from the [autoconf archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/) (specifically [`AX_BOOST_PYTHON`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_boost_python.html#ax_boost_python)))? I can't believe that both boost python and osg provide `main`.

Anyway, to answer the question as asked, you don't have to provide the contents of an `AC_SUBST`'d variable all at once, so you can do stuff like this:

```
myprogram1_LIBS=""
AX_BOOST_PYTHON
myprogram1_LIBS="$myprogram1_LIBS $BOOST_PYTHON_LIB"
# ...
AC_SUBST([myprogram1_LIBS])
```

P.S. the variable to add libraries to a program is [`LDADD` or `myprogram1_LDADD`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Linking.html).

Answer (score 2):

once you add myprogram3 that depends on both `osg` and `boost` you might find it more convenient to separate the checks for libraries from their usage.

e.g. use `configure` only to determine what is there, and use `Makefile` to construct the proper compilation commands.

e.g. (configure.ac):

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([boost_python], [main], [AC_SUBST([BOOST_LIBS], ["-lboost_python"])                      
  AC_DEFINE([HAVE_LIBBOOST_PYTHON], [1], [Define if you have libboost_python])],                  
  [AC_MSG_FAILURE([boost_python library not found])])  
AC_CHECK_LIB([osg], [main], [AC_SUBST([OSG_LIBS], ["-losg"])                      
  AC_DEFINE([HAVE_LIBOSG], [1], [Define if you have libosg])],                  
  [AC_MSG_FAILURE([osg library not found])])
```

and (Makefile.am)

```
myprogram1_LDADD = @BOOST_LIBS@
myprogram2_LDADD = @OSG_LIBS@
myprogram3_LDADD = @BOOST_LIBS@ @OSG_LIBS@
```

Comment: Yea, I've seen that done but the reason I have not done it that way is in my real program I have like 20 libraries being included. I'd prefer to just update the libraries being included in one place rather than in both the configure.ac and the Makefile.am. Is there a compelling reason beyond this for why I in fact should do it this way?