# Save name of found AC_SEARCH_LIBS in a custom variable

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I have a repository which looks something like

```
configure.ac
GNUmakefile.in
src
 |--lib
 |--bin
```

where `src/lib` contains the source for shared libraries to be built, `src/bin` contains the source for several binaries (one of which consists of several static libraries in the same directory).

- Problem 1: some binaries need to link with third-party libraries as well, but not all
- Problem 2: one of these libraries is named differently on Linux and FreeBSD

I saw in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416072/autoconf-append-to-output-variable-and-program-specific-libs) that I can solve problem 1 by using AC_SUBST to save the name of a found library in a custom variable. But how can I save the name of the first found library (whatever it may be) when using a looping macro like `AC_SEARCH_LIBS`, i.e.:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([func], [lib_name_on_linux lib_name_on freebsd], [AC_SUBST([MYLIB], [????])])
```

One workaround would be to have two different invocations to `AC_CHECK_LIB`:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([lib_name_on_linux], [func], [AC_SUBST([MYLIB], ["-llib_name_on_linux"])])
AC_CHECK_LIB([lib_name_on_freebsd], [func], [AC_SUBST([MYLIB], ["-llib_name_on_freebsd"])])
```

This would work since only one of the above `AC_CHECK_LIB` would succeed, but it's ugly and it wouldn't work without additional code if I want to print an error if neither is found. What's the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.66/html_node/Libraries.html), `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` caches the resulting library name in the `ac_cv_search_(function)` variable. It does have two special values (`no` and `none required`) that you'll have to special-case, though. So your code might look something like this:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([func], [libname_linux libname_freebsd], [
  AS_IF([test x$ac_cv_search_func != "xnone required"],
    [MYLIB=$ac_cv_search_func], [MYLIB=])
  AC_SUBST([MYLIB])
], [
  AC_MSG_ERROR([No library found that provides func()])
])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed. Just a small typo: `MYLIB=-l$ac_cv_search_func` should be `MYLIB=$ac_cv_search_func` since the value of `ac_cv_search_func` already has `-l`.